# "Transition-FaceColor" in Matlab

Tags: matlab, colors, background-color, rectangles, colormap

I want to color a rectangle in Matlab with a "transition facecolor" (I do not know the right term) meaning for instance a transition from hell blue to dark blue; you could also interpret it as a shadowing (here you can see an example:

http://il1.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/620653/thumb/1.jpg?i10c=img.resize(height:160)

I could imagine to achieve it by using a colormap, but I do not know how to apply it on a text annotation like a rectangle.

Is it possible to modify Matlab's standard (monochromatic) colors in such a way? And if so, does someone have a basic framework for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the rectangle using a [`patch`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) which allows having interpolated face colors.

Then, in order to have the face color ranging from dark blue to bright blue you have to define your own "blue" `colormap`.

The `colormap` should be defined as a `(N x 3)` `RGB` array: in your case you have to set to `0` the first two columns (corresponding to `red` and `green` and have the values of the third column (the `blue`) ranging from `(start_blue,end_blue)` where `start_blue` is the darkest blue level you want, `end_blue` the brightest (both have to be between `0` and `1`).

```
% Define the rectangle: lower left x, lower left y, width, height
x_rect=1;
y_rect=1;
width=10;
height=5;
% Define the patch vertices and faces
verts=[x_rect y_rect;x_rect y_rect+height; ...
       x_rect+width y_rect+height;x_rect+width y_rect];
faces=[1 2 3 4];
% Define the color: the higher the brighter
col=[0; 0; 4; 4];
figure
% Create the new blue colormap
b=0.7:.01:1;
cm1=[zeros(length(b),2) b']
% Set the new colormap
colormap(cm1)
% Plot the patch
patch('Faces',faces,'Vertices',verts,'FaceVertexCData',col,'FaceColor','interp');
```

As an alternative, you can create the rectangle as a `surf`, then, define your own `colormap` as above.

```
% Define the rectangle:
x_rect=1;
y_rect=1;
width=10;
height=5;
% Build a patch
xp=[x_rect:x_rect+width];
yp=[y_rect:y_rect+height];
% Get the number of points
n_xp=length(xp);
n_yp=length(yp);
% Create the grid
[X,Y]=meshgrid(xp,yp);
% Define the z values
Z=ones(size(X));
% Create the color matrix as uniformly increasing
C=repmat(linspace(1,10,n_xp),n_yp,1)
% Create the new blue colormap
start_blue=0.5;
end_blue=1;
b=start_blue:.01:end_blue;
cm1=[zeros(length(b),2) b']
% Set the new colormap
colormap(cm1)
% Plot the rectangle as a "surf"
surf(X,Y,Z,C)
shading interp

xlabel('X Axis')
ylabel('Y Axis')
view([0 90])
xlim([0 13])
ylim([0 9])
daspect([1 1 1])
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for - you have described it perfectly. Thank you ever so much! Did you make use of this code by your own in the past or do you have created it just for me? Being the latter I highly appreciate it :) Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, happu I've been of use to you. To close the question, could you mark the answer as "accepted".